# Darlington (TIP110) gain value

Tags: transistors, gain

I'm referencing [this Fairchild semiconductor datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/TI/TIP112.pdf) on the TIP112.  (I'm actually working with a TIP110) and trying to evaluate the gain.  In the specs grid on the second page, the sheet states -> 4V Vce/1A Ic the gain is 1000 and at 4V Vce/2A Ic the gain is 500.

*However*, the graph on the next page (figure 2) is quite contradictory to these statements.  Can anyone confirm that this is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are minimum values, the graph on the next page is for *typical* characteristics (notice there are no typical and max values given in the table for DC gain)

The gain of these transistors will vary quite widely from part to part (process variations), so just the minimum guaranteed gain is given. The typical value will usually be quite a bit higher than this value, but you can't rely on this being so.